# How to force the code after await run on the inner scope’s scheduler?

Tags: c#, async-await

I expected that in the absence of `SynchronizationContext`, the execution flow would not change the thread. This code shows that execution flow changes running thread and the code after `await` is executed in a thread from the `ThreadPool`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var ts = new MyTaskScheduler();
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine($"Inside '{Thread.CurrentThread.Name}'"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, ts);
            await t;
            Console.WriteLine($"Outside '{Thread.CurrentThread.Name}'");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class MyTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
    {
        private readonly Thread thread;
        private readonly BlockingCollection<Task> queue;

        public MyTaskScheduler()
        {
            queue = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
            thread = new Thread(() => Loop()) { Name = "my thread" };
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void Loop()
        {
            while (true)
                foreach (var task in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    TryExecuteTask(task);
        }

        protected override void QueueTask(Task task) => queue.Add(task);
        protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) => TryExecuteTask(task);
        protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks() => queue.ToList();
        public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => 1;
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

I can use `TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler` to get the behavior I need. But from its description I can't get whether this is the recommended setting in this case or a side effect with unknown consequences.

Comment: This is a very surprising side-effect. Because you're hiding the scheduler, the `AwaitTaskContinuation` decides it's ok to inline the continuation (it refuses to do so if running in a custom synchronization context or taskscheduler)

Comment: @KevinGosse I'm not sure the OP is correct. `HideScheduler` didn't do anything for me - the behaviour remained the same.

Comment: @pere57 It worked for me. Maybe you have something else preventing inlining. Make sure to run it in a console application (or suppress the synchronization context first)